# jsDoc intellisense for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jsdoc, web-essentials

Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2012 says it has support for jsDoc intellisense, but I can't seen any options for enabling it, and it doesn't appear to do anything.

Any ideas how to turn it on?  or could anyone suggest an alternative extension?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be working fine for me:

[image]

I just tested by following the link [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) to [here](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html) and making a (slightly modified) test file of the first example. I don't know if the entire range of JsDoc functionality is supported.

Comment: ah - maybe i misunderstood what they mean by supports. I was hoping for intellisense support with creating the jsDoc comment block itself, i.e. give me a list of options when i press the @ key.

Comment: No, actually having re-read it I think you are correct. Cheers.

Comment: This is default behavior for Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Its now released (05/05/2013):
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6